# Chrome WebDriver crashes

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using the C# bindings of the Chrome Selenium WebDriver, and navigating to a page will randomly fail. It's not consistent which test it is, but does consistently happen across several tests when the entire suite is run, and it is consistent on the same page change. Below I pasted the code I am using to create the driver instance, the url it's self is not a URL publicly accessible though.

Another consideration is that I am using NUnit to run two test in parallel.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
options.AddArgument("--incognito");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Client, LogLevel.All);
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Server, LogLevel.All);
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Profiler, LogLevel.All);

var driver = new ChromeDriver(DriverPathOnSystem, options);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

**Versions**

- ChromeDriver 2.29
- Chrome 58.0.3029.96 (64 bit)
- Selenium.WebDriver (nuget) 3.4.0
- Selenium.Support (nuget) 3.4.0

**EDIT #1:**
The ChromeDriver is 32bit, and Chrome is 64bit. I did some research, there doesn't appear to be a 64bit ChromeDriver and my research said the two would work- could it be a new bug or something?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling DNS prefetch fixed all the crashes for me. I'm not 100% what it was trying to do that caused the page to crash, maybe it has something to do with npm? Either way, it was a very simple fix:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
options.AddArgument("--incognito");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.AddArgument("--dns-prefetch-disable");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(DriverPathOnSystem, options);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```